# Split a list based on index numbers given by another list

Tags: python

Sorry I'm a beginner and looking for some help dealing with some data..

So I have two lists:

One describes all participants scores in a game
The other contains the number of times each participant played the game

```
scores=['win', 'draw', 'lose', 'lose', 'win', 'win']
trials=[2,3,1]
```

which means there were 3 participants, the first played two times and obtained 'win' and 'draw' etc.

How can I split the scores list so it becomes a nested list with each participants scores as a list? As I want to find a person's average score..

e.g. `splitscores=[['win','draw']['lose','lose','win']['win]]`

I've managed to get the first trial by doing:

```
trial1=[]
for item in scores:
    trial1.append(scores[:trials[0]])
print(trial1)
```

but no clue to get the others by making a loop
Can anyone help? Or is there a better way for me to find a person's average score?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The other answers are good. You can also do it with a simple `for` loop if you find that clearer:

```
scores = ['win', 'draw', 'lose', 'lose', 'win', 'win']
trials = [2, 3, 1]
trial1 = []
# This variable holds the first index of the next sublist
idx = 0
for n in trials:
    trial1.append(scores[idx:idx + n])
    # The next sublist starts where the previous one ended
    idx += n
print(trial1)
```

Output:

```
[['win', 'draw'], ['lose', 'lose', 'win'], ['win']]
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) to sum your `trials` list cumulatively. Then use a list comprehension with slicing:

```
from itertools import accumulate

scores = ['win', 'draw', 'lose', 'lose', 'win', 'win']
trials = [2,3,1]

idx = [0] + list(accumulate(trials))
res = [scores[start:end] for start, end in zip(idx, idx[1:])]

[['win', 'draw'], ['lose', 'lose', 'win'], ['win']]
```

For a truly lazy solution, you can use the `itertools` [`pairwise` recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes):

```
from itertools import accumulate, tee

def pairwise(iterable):
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)

idx = accumulate([0] + trials)
res = [scores[start:end] for start, end in pairwise(idx)]

[['win', 'draw'], ['lose', 'lose', 'win'], ['win']]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can call [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#next) by converting `scores` to a list iterator with [`iter()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#iter):

```
>>> scores=['win', 'draw', 'lose', 'lose', 'win', 'win']
>>> trials=[2,3,1]
>>> scores = iter(scores)
>>> [[next(scores) for i in range(j)] for j in trials]
[['win', 'draw'], ['lose', 'lose', 'win'], ['win']]
```